# How to authenticate AAD user in Identity Server 4?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have integrated the Azure Active Directory in Identity Server 4 as an external provider.

I want to authenticate Azure Active Directory users from Identity Server 4 by using the APIs.

Here is the code:

```
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");

if (disco.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
    return;
}

// request token
var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = "client",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            Scope = "api1",
            UserName = "ad user name",
            Password = "add user password"
        });
```

When I execute this piece of code, I got an invalid username or password error.

**Note**: the provided credentials are valid.

Here is my startup.cs file

```
using IdentityServer4;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers;
using MorpheusIdentityServer.Quickstart.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using IdentityServer4.Validation;

namespace MorpheusIdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

                 

            services.AddAuthentication()
                 .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
                 {

                     options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                     options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                     options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("ActiveDirectoryAuthority").Value;
                     options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("ActiveDirectoryClientId").Value;
                     options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                     options.CallbackPath = "/signin-aad";
                     options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-aad";
                     options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-aad";
                     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         NameClaimType = "name",
                         RoleClaimType = "role",
                         ValidateIssuer = false
                     };

                 });
            services.AddSingleton<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ValidateExternalUser>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            InitializeDatabase(app);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }

        private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();

                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
                if (!context.Clients.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var client in Config.Clients)
                    {
                        context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                if (!context.IdentityResources.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var resource in Config.IdentityResources)
                    {
                        context.IdentityResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                if (!context.ApiScopes.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var resource in Config.ApiScopes)
                    {
                        context.ApiScopes.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ROPC flow with password grant?

Comment: yes, I'm using ROPC flow with password grant

Comment: you check this link , your code looks fine to me ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199330/invalid-grant-aadsts50126-error-validating-credentials-due-to-invalid-username

Comment: What is the value of `disco.TokenEndpoint,` ? and are you passing `openid` in one of your scope `Scope = "api1",`

Comment: The value for disco.TokenEndpoint will be https://localhost:5001/connect/token

Comment: The client configured client: new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client",    
                    EnableLocalLogin=false,
                    ClientName = "Workflow",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
                },

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199330/invalid-grant-aadsts50126-error-validating-credentials-due-to-invalid-username
I have checked this one. It's using azure add token end point. 
my requirement is to use identity server end point and in identity, server use an azure active directory as an external provider

Comment: Do you have any ADFS setup with AAD?

Comment: No, I'm using cloud azure active directory accounts only.

Comment: There are some limitation with ROPC like `The Microsoft identity platform endpoint only supports ROPC for Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. This means that you must use a tenant-specific endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name}) or the organizations endpoint.`

Comment: Where do I need to provide a tenant-specific endpoint? from my code mentioned above.

Comment: Can you post your startup.cs code it's difficult to comment without that. Also make sure your passing `IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,` along with your `Scope = "api1"`

Comment: Added my startup.cs class in question detail. kindly check

Comment: Why are you saying "When I execute this piece of code, I got an invalid username or password error"? AAD should not pass through this part of code. `https://localhost:5001/connect/token` is the token endpoint for Identity Provider users rather than AAD users. I see you have implement `services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect("aad"...)`, which is used to sign in with AAD user. Are you using the "Azure AD button" to login in your application?

Comment: @AllenWu No, from the azure aad button, I'm able to log in. But my requirement is how I may be logged using API with a password of azure aad accounts

Comment: @AllenWu I know this way AAd will not be able to authenticate. let me know how I need to change at the identity server side to work this piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched and found some possible ways to customize usernames and passwords from external providers. Here are the steps

1- Implement a class like below

```
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
       var username= context.UserName;
       var password= context.Password;
      // write the code which will validate the username and password from external provider.    
    }
}
```

2- Then register this interface in a startup.cs file like below:

```
services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

So, when you try to call the endpoint /connect/token this class will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

By default `Resource Owner Password` workflow uses the `connect/token` endpoint which validates the users who are present in the `AspNetUser` table only (it will not validate external users), so that's the reason you are getting the `Invalid User name or password` error message because your user is present in Microsoft AD and not in ID4 database.

Log in using the `Resource Owner Password` password isn't the recommended approach but if you still need it anyway, you can override the endpoint implementation and write your own custom logic to authenticate the user with a Microsoft AD data source.

Comment: How do I write custom logic and at which place to authenticate a user from an external provider?

Comment: You can create/override endpoint by implementing the `IEndpointHandler` interface. Please take a look at my [blog post](https://dev.to/maheshmore2691/identity-server-4-with-net-core-app-4ih0) where I have added detailed steps for custom handlers.