# Migrate loginWithUsernamePassword to @azure/identity

Tags: node.js, azure, msal.js, azure-identity, ropc

I migrate some code from [@azure/ms-node-auth](https://github.com/Azure/ms-rest-nodeauth) to [@azure/identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/44712109c705d23d5ec52d98a3a508157674df84/sdk/identity/identity) which authenticates against Azure Active Directory (AAD) via `loginWithUsernamePassword`. The [migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/ms-rest-nodeauth/blob/master/migrate-to-identity-v2.md) points to `UsernamePasswordCredential` class, but it denies my request.

```
// Working @azure/ms-node-auth snippet
async function getTokenLegacy(): Promise<string> {
  const credentials = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithUsernamePassword(
    USERNAME,
    PASSWORD, {
      domain: AAD_TENANT_ID,
      clientId: CUSTOM_CLIENT_ID,
      tokenAudience: CUSTOM_APP_ID,
    },
  );
  return (await credentials.getToken()).accessToken;
}

// Non-working migrated @azure/identity version
async function getTokenMigrated(): Promise<string> {
  const credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredential(
    AAD_TENANT_ID, 
    CUSTOM_CLIENT_ID, 
    USERNAME, 
    PASSWORD);
  return (await credentials.getToken(CUSTOM_APP_ID)).token;
}
```

The following error occurs.

```
AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.
```

The user has a `federated` account and `@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth` verifies the credentials via the `SAML` protocol.

```
UserRealm: VERBOSE: UserRealm response:
UserRealm: VERBOSE:  AccountType:             federated
UserRealm: VERBOSE:  FederationProtocol:      wstrust
TokenRequest: VERBOSE: Acquiring token with username password for federated user
...
WSTrustResponse: INFO: Found token of type: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion
TokenRequest: VERBOSE: Performing OAuth assertion grant type exchange.
```

Comment: Hello @sschmeck, Could you please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199330/invalid-grant-aadsts50126-error-validating-credentials-due-to-invalid-username ,May it helps

Comment: Creating a cloud only user isn't easiely achievable in my environment. Therefore I search for another solution, @AjayKumarGhose-MT

Answer (score 0):

- Please try resetting the password, otherwise you can use the below workaround
- As you are using ***federated authentication*** you will get ***redirected*** to the **federated identity** for verification.
  When you are using `ropc` flow by passing the username and password the redirection does not happen and gives an error of `invalid username or password` .

In order to make this work you need to **disable federated authentication** and use **manage authentication from AAD** site so that no redirection is required .
So you will need to create a user from AAD site .

For more information please refer this [***MS Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/38035/aadsts50126-invalid-grant-error-validating-credent.html) answer suggested by @amanpreetsingh-msft & @MarileeTurscak-MSFT .

Still , if you want to use **federated authentication** you can refer this [***blog***](https://medium.com/@amanmcse/ropc-username-password-flow-fails-with-aadsts50126-invalid-username-or-password-for-federated-90c666b4808d) .